# Will this code prevent SQL injection (Python)

Tags: python, sql

Please let me know will following codes 100% prevent SQL injection in python

*Sample1*

```
username = request.GET('username')  # non-filtered user input
connection.execute("SELECT id,name,email FROM user WHERE username=%s LIMIT 1", (username,))
```

*Sample2*

```
username = request.POST('username')  # non-filtered user input
name = request.POST('name')  # non-filtered user input
email = request.POST('email')  # non-filtered user input
connection.execute("UPDATE user SET name=%s, email= %s WHERE username=%s LIMIT 1", (name, email, username,))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of the %s is to isolate the data from the query. When you pass two arguments, they are combined in the module. It is intended to mitigate injection, but I'd be hesitant to say "100%"

Edit: many wiser than myself (maybe even real life security experts!) have weighed in here:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15214/are-prepared-statements-100-safe-against-sql-injection

Comment: Even if I wouldn't say "100%", I'd say that for anyone asking this question, the database library is likely to do a better job of it than you are, so it's almost certainly the right answer. Which is why dbapi-2.0 and every database library that implements it all suggest using parameters, with a link to [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Agreed. Don't take it at face value for a banking website, but do this and find a bigger hole to plug.

Comment: This is the right way of doing it.  Why would you hesitate to say 100%?

Comment: @DavidWallace, I don't know which SQL module is being used, and haven't read the source code to see what exactly it is doing. But feel free to say 100% if you'd like :)

Comment: @mhlester I am using MySQLdb (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) driver. What i need to do for maximum secure sql query. I think the code i used 'is a kind' of prepared statements in python.