# write multiple foods to DB from JSON

Tags: python, mysql, json

I am currently having major issues writing foods from a JSON to my database. The GET method works just fine. However, when I receive a JSON, it is not properly writing to the database.

What I do is the following

- Write a new meal to the database (creates a new meal/cart id via autoincrement)
- Utilize the LAST_INSERT_ID() command to write new foods to that meal/cart.

Once I get here writing one food is fine, however if there is numerous foods, I can't seem to get it to write the other foods from the JSON to the database.

The JSON I am receiving is as follows:

```
Endpoint: /meallog
Request params:{ 
                 method: ”post”,
                 headers: headers,
                 url: string,
                 data:{
                       userId: string,
                       date: string,
                       mealData:{
                                 mealName: String,
                                 food: [
                                        {
                                         id:string,
                                         foodname:string,
                                         numCal:int,
                                         servingSize:int,
                                         servingSizeUnit:string,
                                         totalCalories:int  
                                        },
                                        {
                                         (repeat above)
                                        }
                                       ]
                                 }

                       }
}
Response: (JSON Object)
{
     code: 200/400,
     message: String
}
```

The Code I currently have for my post is below:

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    jsondata = {}
    code={}

    user_id = request.json['user_id']
    date = request.json['date']
    mealName = request.json['mealName']
    food_id = request.json['id']
    food_name = request.json['foodname']
    food_cal = request.json['numCal']
    serving_size = request.json['servingSize']
    serving_unit = request.json['servingSizeUnit']
    totalCal = request.json['totalCalories']

    postmeal = conn.cursor()
    INS_meal = "INSERT INTO user_cart (user_id, datetime, cart_cal, cart_name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
    postmeal.execute(INS_meal, (user_id, date, totalCal, mealName))
    conn.commit()        

    postfood = conn.cursor()
    INS_food = "INSERT INTO food_log VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
    postfood.execute(INS_food, (food_id, food_name, food_cal, serving_size, serving_unit))
    conn.commit()   

    if postfood.execute and postmeal.execute:
        code['code'] = '200'
        code['message'] = 'Success! INSERTED values into both food_log and user_cart'
    else:
        code['code'] = '400'
        code['message'] = 'Error Connecting to DB. Cant insert into food_log and-or user_cart'

    jsondata['code'] = code['code']
    jsondata['message'] = code['message']

    return(json.dumps(jsondata))
```

Essentially I'd like it to gather every food that comes in, and write the entire food objects in the array to the food table seamlessly.

Comment: Writing to avoid [Python SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106177/will-this-code-prevent-sql-injection-python) would be good, you probably learnt that with PHP. Knowing the error/results would be good. Happy Turkey genocide day to you too :-)

Comment: no error messages on my end. if there are multiple foods in the array, however, it will only write the first object coming in. Say if the user in mealData with cart id 11 had an apple and a banana, it would only write apple to cart id and then stop.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue and utilized LAST_INSERT_ID() in a more structured way, as well as to properly loop through the foods incoming.

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    jsondata = {}
    code={}

    #with open('inc.json') as json_data:
        #d = json.load(json_data)
        #print(d)
    user_id = request.json['userId']
    date = request.json['date']

    mealName = request.json['mealData']['mealName']

    foodlist = request.json['mealData']['food']        

    postmeal = conn.cursor()
    INS_meal = "INSERT INTO user_cart (user_id, datetime, cart_name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
    postmeal.execute(INS_meal, (user_id, date, mealName))
    conn.commit()        
    postmeal.execute("select LAST_INSERT_ID();")
    SEL_MEAL_ID = postmeal.fetchone()[0]

    food_str = ""
    for food in foodlist:
        print (food)
        food_str+="({}, '{}', '{}', {}, {}, '{}', {}), ".format(SEL_MEAL_ID, food['id'], food['foodname'], food['numCal'], food['servingSize'], food['servingSizeUnit'], food['totalCalories'])

    postfood = conn.cursor()
    INS_food = "INSERT INTO food_log VALUES {};".format(food_str[:-2]) # To exclude the last comma in the food string
    postfood.execute(INS_food)
    conn.commit()   

    if postfood.execute and postmeal.execute:
        code['code'] = '200'
        code['message'] = 'Success! INSERTED values into both food_log and user_cart'
    else:
        code['code'] = '400'
        code['message'] = 'Error Connecting to DB. Cant insert into food_log and-or user_cart'

    jsondata['code'] = code['code']
    jsondata['message'] = code['message']

    return(json.dumps(jsondata))
```